# Optimized variable declaration primitive vs null object

Tags: java, memory, optimization

I have a class called Location which has 2 type of information, one is a nodeID (a integer) and another is diskPosition (a long).
My application needs to create many objects of this Location class but most of the time I will assign a default value (say -1) to one of these two variable inside the class Location.

My question is "should I declare these nodeID and diskPosition as Integer and Long and assign default value null instead of keeping them as primitive and assigning default value as -1)"

My concern is amount of memory being taken by my Location object and I want to minimize it.

Below is code snippet of Location class:

```
public class Location
{
    private int     nodeID  = -1;
    private long    diskPos = -1;

    public Location(long diskPos)
    {
        this.diskPos = diskPos;
    }

    public Location(Node node)
    {
        this.nodeID = node.getNodeID();
    }

    // Test main method to elaborate usage of Location object
    public void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<Integer, Location> cellIDToLocationMap = new HashMap<Integer, Location>();

        // Consider there is a list of nodes which is obtained from somewhere
        List<Node> nodeList = getNodeList();

        Location loc = null;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                loc = new Location(nodeList.get(i));
            else
                loc = new Location(i);

            // Put in map
            cellIDToLocationMap.put(i, loc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do you _use_ `Location` after that?

Comment: Why would you mandatory place these two fields in the class in the first place, if the values are often default ones? This screams for inheritance,

Comment: @Smutje - How will inheritance help?. nodeID and diskPos are (and should be) at instance level. And they have to be unique to all Location instances (unless I misunderstood the question :) ).

Comment: Default values break unique constraints.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, primitives take less memory than objects.

Comment: You may forgot to override ```hashCode``` and ```equals``` even if that is not the answer.

Comment: @WhoAmI you can make Location an interface with methods `getDiskPos` and `getNodeID`, and use up to 4 implementing classes. One without fields where both getters return -1 (single instance, practically no memory cost), one with only the NodeID, and so on. This is much easier if your instances are immutable (i.e. final fields).

Comment: Why dont you have a Location interface with a single method like long getPosition() and two implementations -one for node and other one for disk position.

Comment: @Chris Isn't there some overhead with inheritance? I think it would offset any memory savings.

Comment: @Chris - But the fields aren't final. Using an interface then a class which implements that interface but returns -1, then another class which returns some other value. Do you think that this complexity is needed here?.

Comment: @WhoAmI Even if not final, they are not modified in the OPs example. But we would need more info to now if such a micro-optimization (instance size would probably go from 24 down to 16 bytes) is needed. I highly doubt that - you'd need at least 10-100 million location instances to make any difference. Hardly likely.

Comment: Your code snippet suggests that you have either a nodeId or a diskPos. So i would recommend to create two classes with a super class/interface: `DiskPosLocation` and `IdLocation`.

Comment: @schmop Inheritance concerns only the class object and thus has no memory cost. Performance cost is negligible, too (in HotSpot, at least). But as mentioned above, I would only consider this for added clarity, not for memory savings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on how many instances you create and on the distribution of the `nodeID` and `diskPos` values. Let's look at the numbers, assuming a 32-bit JVM (or 64-bit with pointer compression). The values might still not match your JVM implementation, but they should be correct for HotSpot.

With `int` and `long` a `Location` instance takes 24 bytes. With `Integer` and `Long`, it depends. The `Location` instances takes 16 bytes, and the `Integer` and `Long` objects *might* take 16 each, unless they are shared. If, as you say, one of them stays -1 (or `null`) most of the time, that takes no memory, so that makes either 16 or 32 bytes total. Whether `Integer` or `Long` instances are shared depends on the value and the JVM settings. As `diskPos` needs to be long, it's quite unlikely the the instances would be cached.

So the answer is: primitive = 24 bytes, boxed very likely 32 bytes. Stay with the primitives.

You *could* get memory consumption down to 16 bytes per instance if you use different classes implementing a common interface. I would not do this for the memory savings (you'd need millions of instances before you even notice), but for more readable code, since, with one of the field -1, `Location` is effectively a union type, and you probably have code like this:

```
if (location.getNodeId() >= 0) {
    // do something with node id
} else {
    // do something with diskPos
}
```

A more object oriented design would let you incorporate the different behavior into the respective classes.